# Special Special Relativity Question

Tags: special-relativity, velocity, inertial-frames, faster-than-light

According to what I've learned from physics professors, no object can go faster than the speed of light. So if you have object A moving .8c one way and object B moving .8c the opposite way...relative to each other that is 1.6c? How do they appear to each other (or to a third stationary point in the middle in communication with each side)

Answer (score 4):

No, you can not use the Galilean sum of velocities. You have to use the one derived from Special Relativity:

$$u=\frac{u'+v}{1+\frac{u'\text{ }{}{}v}{c^2}}$$

Imagine you have a train moving at $v$. The velocity of a ball throwed inside the train will be $u'$. The ball's velocity that at observer in rest will measure will be calculated using the previous law of adition of velocities.

As you can see, this law of adition of velocities prevent of being in a superluminical case.